# How to select a default USB device in a Debug Configuration in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In a **Run/Debug Configuration**, you can select **Emulator** and select a **Prefer Android Virtual Device**. But how do you select a "**Prefer Android Device**" when you select "**USB device**", so that you won't be prompted to choose which USB device when debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is actually possible. I would hazard a guess that it won't let you because it can't guarantee that you'll always have that device plugged in when you go to run/debug your app.

Comment: Thanks, it can just prompt if the selected device is unplugged. This is how Xamarin Android works. I will request this feature in the group.

Comment: The the studio would say, "woops, we couldn't connect to the device. Please check the connection and try again." just like Visual Studio has said since the begining.